# Trying to segue to another view controller using an alert action, in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my code I have an action sheet that allows a user to either log-in or sign-up. When the user presses either one of these I want to define a handler that will segue them to the login/signup view controller. I'm very new to this so I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong but in my code I get an error that the types are not convertible. The code looks like this:

```
let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Do you have an account?", message: "Please Log-In or Sign-Up", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
    if let presentationController = actionSheet.popoverPresentationController {
        presentationController.sourceView = sender as UIView
        presentationController.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    }

    let dismissHandler = {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    let signupHandler = ({
        (ViewController: UIViewController!) in
        let signupVC: nextViewController = segue.signupVC as nextViewController
    })
    let loginHandler = ({
        (ViewController: UIViewController!) in
        let loginVC: nextViewController = segue.loginVC as nextViewController
    })
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: dismissHandler))
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log-In", style: .Default, handler: dismissHandler))
    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Sign-Up", style: .Default, handler: signupHandler))
    presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know about segues but I normally just present them like this :

```
let loginVC = LoginViewController()
self.presentViewController(loginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hey, that worked! Thanks. However, now, when it presents that new ViewController, the screen is just black... Any idea why? In the LoginViewController class I called super.viewDidLoad()...

Comment: Have you set the ViewController in the Identity Inspector?

Comment: I believe so. I named it SignupViewController (working on sign-up rather than log-in) and the code looks like this `let signupVC = SignupViewController()
            self.presentViewController(signupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`